# Error: Status 500 - TempData ViewModel with ajax call

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have problem with TempData.If i use View Model for TempData it gives me a error 500 , but if i use string on something else on TempData it works fine ...

Here is code of action

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetKorpaItems(List<int> values,List <string> values2, List<int> values3)
    {
        NarudjbaInfoVM model = new NarudjbaInfoVM();
        model.stavke = new List<NarudjbaInfoVM.ProizvodV>();
        for (int i = 1; i < values.Count; i++)
        {
            Proizvod a = proizvodiService.GetProizvodById(values[i]);

            model.stavke.Add(new NarudjbaInfoVM.ProizvodV
            {
                ProizvodID = a.ProizvodID,
                VrstaProizvoda = values2[i],
                TrazenaKolicina = values3[i],
                Cijena = a.Cijena
            });

            model.IznosBezPDV += a.Cijena;
            model.IznosSaPDV += a.Cijena;
        }
        TempData["Model"] = model;
        return Json(new { message = "Success" });
    }
```

Comment: This needs more details, assigning an object to the TempData should work fine. What's the error in the function exactly? will you debug it?

Comment: Please edit the question and add your controller/view code that is referring to the TempData.

Comment: Posting the exception details would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`TempData["Model"] = model;`
WILL NOT assign the object and its properties to TempData. What this would do is do a convert the object to a string.

Hence the result will be a string with namespace + class name;

```
YourNamespace.NarudjbaInfoVM
```

Even casting explicitly to the object you want with `((NarudjbaInfoVM)model)` won't work and will still output a string.

What you should do is just include it in your json result, this will automatically convert your model to a JSON object.

```
return Json(model);
```

Comment: ty for answering , but i need to use that ViewModel in another action . Can i get him after sending him as Json.

Comment: How are you using the viewmodel after the json return? Can I see that code that uses the tempdata?

Comment: i dont have it , i want to take that model and create a new action , and in that action i will use that model. But when i use tempdata for string or int , action return success without error , but when i  use that view model for tempdata it cause a error. Sorry for my bad english if u cant understand me ...